# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Where is the method to write custom SQL and get result set back?

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

I have been reading on 
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite
to find methods so I can execute normal SQL (string commands), and get a result set back, but I dont think there is any.

I am testing OrmLite v 4.0.17.0.

On the page above, there is a method *SqlList* mentioned, but I have no such method available:

[image]

I have an ExecuteSql, but I get no result set back, just an int:

[image]

So, two questions:

1. Is there a way to execute custom queries, a method that takes in a string as parameter, and where I then get back a result set, rows or objects or something?
2. And while I am at it, how do I create a "LIMIT", for example "SELECT * FROM a LIMIT 10"?

Here is the version info:

[image]

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/37430646/2931053 for where to find Limit().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I recently noticed that `db.SqlList` got lost in the [OrmLite v4 refactor](https://plus.google.com/+DemisBellot/posts/Sbd5113dRrd) so I've restored it [back in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/2b133f6c98774e40a996fc9ab955b130020984a5). Which will be available in the next release of v4, before the end of the month.

You can still use `db.Select` for raw SELECT queries, e.g:

```
var results = db.Select<Poco>("SELECT * FROM a LIMIT 10");
```

It's only an issue when it's not a **SELECT** statement because we'd assume it's short-hand like:

```
var results = db.Select<Poco>("Foo = 'bar'");
```

And automatically add the rest of the SQL for you, but this is a problem when you're not issuing a `SELECT` statement, e.g. calling a stored procedure, which is what `db.SqlList` is for since the raw SQL remains untouched.

#### Support for LIMIT in Typed Expression API

Another way to query with a limit is to use the typed expression API, e.g:

```
var results = db.Select<Poco>(q => q.Limit(10));
```