# Why does the "Limit()" method no longer exist in the ServiceStack OrmLite v4?

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack, micro-orm

in ServiceStack OrmLite v3 you could do:

```
var rows = db.Select<Employee>().Limit(10));
```

Or:

```
var rows = db.Select<Employee>().Limit(5, 10)); // skips 5 then takes 10
```

However I cannot find these methods any longer in v4.

I suppose I can do the following instead:

```
var rows = db.SelectLazy<Employee>().Take(10);
```

However how can I do a `db.Select` (not having to write direct SQL) which will translate to (in SQLite for example):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee LIMIT 10;
```

Also, is it possible to write an equivalent query for the below (again without having to write direct SQL)?

```
SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY Age;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In ServiceStack.OrmLite v4, Limit() seems to only be available as an extension of `SqlExpression<T>`. To build a query:

```
var query = db.From<SWChars>().Limit(10);
query = query.Where<SWChars>(char => 
    char.FirstName == "Jar Jar" &&
    char.FunnyLines < 0);

var result = db.Select<SWChars>(query);
```

I hope this helps someone out. It took me a few hours of Googling.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending` in the documentation, it looks like:

```
var rows = db.SelectLazy<Employee>().OrderBy<Employee>(e=>e.Age).Take(10);
```

This might help with the `Limit` issue [ServiceStack.OrmLite: Where is the method to write custom SQL and get result set back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999864/servicestack-ormlite-where-is-the-method-to-write-custom-sql-and-get-result-set)

Comment: the link you have posted is Great, very very close to what I want however it doesn't work with "SelectLazy" only works with "Select" it would be good if one could return IEnumerable instead